# Can't find "clear flags" option in the camera's inspector

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-development, unity3d-editor

I have two unity projects open and I just noticed that the inspector for the camera object is different between the two.
The Picture below shows inspector of both projects. I am used to the inspector on the left from tutorials. Is there a reason why the inspector on other project looks different ?

I want to change "clear flag" to *depth only* but I am not finding this option in the inspector of the other project (also under "Background Type" there is no *depth only* option). Is there another way to get the same effect as *depth only* on the second inspector?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the flag is missing in the second image is because that project is using the [Universal Render Pipeline (URP)](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@16.0/manual/index.html) instead of the Built-in Render Pipeline.

Based on the [Camera documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@16.0/manual/camera-component-reference.html), **Background Type** contains the functionality now, with the options:

- Skybox
- Solid Color
- Uninitialized

[image]

You'll note that "Depth only" isn't an option here. According to the [FAQs for the URP](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@16.0/manual/faq.html), the following reason was given for why this is the case:

> We’ve deprecated camera clear flags in LWRP. Instead, you can set the
> Background Type in the Camera Inspector. We’ve done this because the
> clear flags Depth Only and Don’t Care from the Built-in render
> pipeline has inherent performance pitfalls. The clear flags were used
> for camera stacking, where one camera depends on the results of a
> previous camera. This is bad for performance, as it executes culling
> multiple times and increases bandwidth. Bandwidth cost is especially
> important for mobile games.
>
> For these reasons, we're working on a solution where you can add a
> render pass with custom camera matrices and FOV. This way, we can
> provide an optimized workflow instead of creating a Camera object. We
> plan to expose this custom render pass in a future LWRP package.

From the sounds of it, this functionality can't be readily reproduced in the URP, though they're working on a future solution to make it possible again.